# Adding header to Ajax request

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How can I add a request header to an ExtJS ajax request?

I specifically want to add the header: `accept-encoding` to equal true.

Comment: You question is very unclear. Perhaps you can be more descriptive as for what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Izhaki I clarified it to my understanding of the question. Hopefully I didn't take too many liberties with it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify request headers like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'yourUrl',
    headers: {
        'accept-encoding': 'true'
    }
})​
```

Comment: does this works also for loading stores (as a config of load at the same level as params ?)

Comment: Hi @code4jhon, you want something like this to set headers on a stores proxy: Ext.getStore('YourStore').proxy.headers = {'accept-encoding': 'true'}

Comment: yeah, added config when defining the store. (config in the proxy obviously) thanks works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [**`headers`**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) config in the Ajax request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'someURL',
    headers: {
        'accept-encoding': true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add a header to *all* Extjs ajax requests:

```
Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
    'accept-encoding' : true
};
```

Answer (score 3):

With ExtJs 6. Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders doesn't work.
But using the following setter works

```
Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
    'accept-encoding' : true
});
```